# Is it possible to sync an azure repo with MWAA (Amazon Workflows for Apache Airflow)?

Tags: amazon-s3, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, repository, mwaa

I have set up a private MWAA instance in AWS. It has set up a bucket that stores DAGs in S3.
I've created a private repository in Azure DevOps and have set up a role that can access this bucket.

With Azure-Pipelines is it possible to sync the entire repository to control the DAGs created/modified in that S3 bucket?

I've seen it's possible to create artefacts and push them to the S3 bucket, but what if a dag is deleted? The DAG will still persist in the S3 Bucket and will still be available in MWAA.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sync entire repository to S3 bucket,you can use the task `Amazon S3 Upload` in your azure pipeline.

[image: upload to S3]

I'm not sure if that will fully address your problem, though.

If there is any misunderstanding, please feel free to add comments related to your issue.

Comment: @Yanzal Does this task work for you?